# How to deploy 'create-react-app' to Heroku with custom back-end api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a 'create-react-app' project to Heroku. I used the [Heroku Create-React-App](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) boilerplate and followed another tutorial on [setting up a backend api](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0) for connecting to my custom `server.js` file.

When I deploy to Heroku, the build runs fine but my app still will not connect to my `server.js` file.

I assume this is either because the `proxy` property in my `package.json` is supposed to point to the same port defined in my `server.js` file (which Heroku would assign automatically, which I don't know how to check) or perhaps my `server.js` file isn't running at all.

Been having a very hard time finding any resources that properly explain how to deploy a 'create-react-app' with a custom back-end (server.js).

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "proxy": "https://localhost:5000",
    "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^0.17.1",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
      "md5": "^2.2.1",
      "mongodb": "^3.0.2",
      "react": "^16.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
      "react-router": "^4.2.0",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "start:server":"node server.js",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    }
}
```

Line in `server.js` where I set the port:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
```

Comment: Above `package.json` is from server side (express) or client side(create-react-app) ?

Comment: I guess client-side. I've never worked on a project with separate `package.json` files for the front and back-end, I just have the one in the root folder.

Comment: is there any specific path you are trying to get from `server.js` i.e any `auth` or anything else ? If yes can you provide the `route` to the path ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The server.js file contains all code my front-end (react code) connects to via AJAX (axios), so when you go to a sub-route (www.example.com/playlist) it returns the json for that route. It's a very simple api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to deploy my app to Heroku by following [this tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/) from fullstackreact.com and studying the accompanying repo.

Basically, I needed to bundle my client-side code and then make sure my server.js file was serving that bundle as a static file. I'm sure there's other ways to go about this, like running concurrent scripts for the webpack-dev-server and the backend api (server.js), but this worked for me without much headaches.